# pom changes needed to get JIRA link

Tags: maven

How do I configure my changes.xml and pom file in order to link JIRA issue on the maven site.
I am including the maven-changes plugin. But I want to see how do we add for JIRA as I add the following for bugzilla.

JIRA
      https://bugs.abc.corp/enter_bug.cgi?product=${project.groupId}&component=${project.artifactId}

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-changes-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
           <issueLinkTemplatePerSystem>
              <bugzilla><![CDATA[http://internal.bugtracker/show_bug.cgi?id=%ISSUE%]]></bugzilla>
              <navigator><![CDATA[http://external.bugtracker/?cr=%ISSUE%]]></navigator>
           </issueLinkTemplatePerSystem>
        </configuration>
        <reportSets>
           <reportSet>
              <reports>
                 <report>changes-report</report>
              </reports>
           </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
     </plugin>
     <plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it is a great idea to take a look at the docs, as Raghuram suggested. JIRA is one of the pre-configured systems, and its standard URL for issues is %URL%/%ISSUE%.

From the XML snippet I understand you have added the issueLinkTemplatePerSystem configuration in the **reporting** section of the pom file. I have been struggling with this until I have tried adding that configuration to the **pluginManagement** section instead:

```
<project>
    <!-- ... -->
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-changes-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <issueLinkTemplatePerSystem>
                            <system1>https://a.b.c/ticket?id=%ISSUE%</system1>
                            <system2>https://foo.bar/baz/%ISSUE%/view</system2>
                        </issueLinkTemplatePerSystem>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- ... -->
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <!-- ... -->
    </build>
    <!-- ... -->
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-changes-plugin</artifactId>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>changes-report</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <!-- ... -->
</project>
```

Then it worked like a charm, being able to use several different systems (with different template URLs) in changes.xml. I did not find this in the documentation.

Hint: try adding the option --debug (mvn --debug clean changes:changes-report) to see the IMSs taken by the plugin from the configuration.

Comment: I got it working under the usual reporting section as well on the same lines. Will add a separate comment to paste the section

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try the steps documented in *Linking to Your Issue Management System* section of the [usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/usage.html) page of the plugin.

According to it, from version 2.4, the plugin comes pre-configured for a bunch of issue tracking systems, including jira. Quoting from the page,

> If you use the issue attribute in your changes.xml file and have the
>    element configured in your pom.xml, the report will
>   contain links to the issues in your issue management system.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it working for bugzilla and jira. So you just need to add an extra row -
You may put the url instead of the variable "%"

```
<reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-changes-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <issueLinkTemplatePerSystem>
                        <jira><![CDATA[%URL%/browse/%ISSUE%]]></jira>
                        <bugzilla><![CDATA[http://bugzill.url/show_bug.cgi?id=%ISSUE%]]></bugzilla>
                    </issueLinkTemplatePerSystem>
                </configuration>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>changes-report</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</reporting>
```